# Git 1.9 double asterisk in negated pattern not working?

Tags: git, gitignore

Our folder structure looks like this:

```
x
├─y
│ ├─a
│ │ ├─config.xml
│ │ ├─a.file
│ │ └─another.file
│ ├─b
│ │ ├─config.xml
│ │ ├─a.file
│ │ └─another.file
│ └─config.xml
├─z
│ └─(...)
└─config.xml
```

I want to add all config.xml to the Git repository.

I'm trying to do this with the following .gitignore placed at the repostory's top level

```
*
!**/config.xml
```

The only file, that git status lists is x/config.xml. The others are ignored. We are using Git 1.9.0-rc3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*
!**/
!**/config.xml
```

*And this is min answer length padding padding padding.*

Comment: This is because git doesn't inspect ignored folders, isn't it? 

When i change my .gitignore to your version, git status only displays the folders y and z as untracked files.

Comment: @BlackEye It doesn't care about folders, at all, but it does care about full file paths and their wildcards. Use `git status -u` to see full listings, not just folders.

Comment: Actually yes, this solution is necessary because "It is not possible to re-include a file if [or, while] a parent directory of that file is excluded" ([source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)). Git does not inspect ignored folders for re-including files due to performance reasons.